# sklearn's cross_validate does not work with catboost

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation, boosting

I would like to use cross validation with `catboost`. Since I do not just want to use `catboost` but also sampling I am using a pipeline and hence cannot use `catboost's` own cross validation (which works if I just use `catboost` and not a pipeline). So I want to use `sklearn's` cross validation, which works fine if I use just numerical variables but as soon as I also include the categorical variables (`cat_features`) and use `catboost's` encoding, `cross_validate` doesn't work anymore. Even if I don't use a pipeline but just `catboost` alone I get a `KeyError: 0` message with `cross_validate`. But I don't understand why.
This is part of my code that doesn't work:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
model = cb.CatBoostClassifier(**params, cat_features=cat_features)
cv_score = cross_validate(model, X_train, y_train, scoring='roc_auc', cv=5, return_train_score=True)
```

Comment: Could you identify where in the error traceback the KeyError is happening?  Are your `cat_features` strings/column names, or integers/column indices?

Comment: My cat_features are object and category types. The KeyError happens already in the beginning, the error message starts like this: KeyError Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2656             try:
-> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
....
KeyError: 0
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: I think it is because sklearn's ```cross_validate``` cannot really encode the categorical features while fitting the data. It's probably a problem of sklearn's ```cross_validate``` as everything works perfectly fine when doing the same thing but using model.fit.

Comment: I can't recreate the error.  See https://github.com/bmreiniger/datascience.stackexchange/blob/master/58181-catboost&skl_cross_validate.ipynb .  Can you share your code, data, and/or full traceback?

Comment: thanks for the example! Your example works with me, but your cat_feature is of type int, but i have cat_features of type O or category (which is the problem, I think).

Comment: for example this column throws me that error. CategoricalDtype(categories=['1', '3', '100', '144', '1', '101', '102', '103', '4',
                  '105',
                  ...
                  'a8', 'f4', 'd93', 'aB1', 'aB3', 't7T', 'a97T', 'a1', 't2',
                  'Unknown'],
                 ordered=False)

Comment: I found out when i do xtrain.astype('O') it works.

Comment: Ah, good work.  Please make that an answer then.  Here's a reference to follow up: https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/814

Answer (score 2):

I found out that adding `xtrain.astype('O')` works.

Apparently catboost doesn't work with pandas Categorical dtypes yet: https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/814